# Read files in sequence with MULE

Tags: file, mule

I'm using a File Inbound Endpoint in Mule to process files from one directory and after processing move the files to another directory. The problem I have is that sometimes there's a lot of files in the "incoming directory" and when MULE starts up it tries to process them concurrently. This is no good for the DB accessed and updated in the flow. Can the files be read in sequence, no matter what order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the flow processing strategy to synchronous to ensure the file poller thread gets mobilized across the flow.

```
<flow name="filePoller" processingStrategy="synchronous">
```

On top of that, do not use any `<async>` block or `one-way` endpoint downstream in the flow, otherwise, another thread pool will kick in, leading to potential (and undesired for your use case) parallel processing.

Comment: Thank you very much! This made IT! /Claes